# Outgoing spam from postfix using my domains

Tags: linux, postfix, spam

I get a lot of spam outgoing from my server which uses fake emails but real domains (that are hosted on my server Linux Debian Squeeze). These all have "msg" plus a random number as Email address. Here is an example from the log :

Jun 25 09:46:18 ks4000003 postfix/qmgr[17823]: 7EA0C201608F: from=, size=1825, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 25 09:46:18 ks4000003 amavis[11085]: (11085-20) Passed CLEAN, LOCAL [127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1]  -> , Message-ID: <1109200188.5353705.1466862379262@atableqc.ca>, mail_id: ELwtXTha8l9Y, Hits: -0.9, size: 1318, queued_as: 7EA0C201608F, 688 ms

I can't get to find where this is coming from. I changed root password, didn't change anyway. Here is an example of message headers, which shows this is not coming from a PHP script or anything:

```
*** MESSAGE CONTENTS deferred/3/3CE1E2016092 ***
regular_text: Received: from localhost (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
regular_text:   by ks4000003.ip-198-245-60.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id 3CE1E2016092
regular_text:   for <joergpahl@aol.com>; Sat, 25 Jun 2016 09:29:52 -0400 (EDT)
regular_text: X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at ks4000003.ip-198-245-60.net
regular_text: Received: from ks4000003.ip-198-245-60.net ([127.0.0.1])
regular_text:   by localhost (ks4000003.ip-198-245-60.net [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024)
regular_text:   with ESMTP id WOgKWhIoZTkR for <joergpahl@aol.com>;
regular_text:   Sat, 25 Jun 2016 09:29:51 -0400 (EDT)
regular_text: Received: from blogs.annuairedesign.com (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
regular_text:   by ks4000003.ip-198-245-60.net (Postfix) with ESMTP id 9F7E6201608E
regular_text:   for <joergpahl@aol.com>; Sat, 25 Jun 2016 09:29:51 -0400 (EDT)
regular_text: Date: Sat, 25 Jun 2016 13:29:53 +0000 (UTC)
regular_text: From: MKP Solutions <msg1466861393@blogs.annuairedesign.com>
regular_text: To: joergpahl@aol.com
regular_text: Message-ID: <1440779940.5330679.1466861393249@blogs.annuairedesign.com>
regular_text: Subject: Hi joergpahl
regular_text: MIME-Version: 1.0
regular_text: Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
regular_text:   boundary="----=_Part_5330678_1709585627.1466861393249"
regular_text: X-mailer: Mailer v1.0
regular_text: 
regular_text: ------=_Part_5330678_1709585627.1466861393249
regular_text: Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
regular_text: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
regular_text: 
regular_text: Medicines pricing you can smile about. Learn more
regular_text: ------=_Part_5330678_1709585627.1466861393249
regular_text: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
regular_text: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

postconf -n :

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
always_add_missing_headers = yes
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 10
disable_vrfy_command = yes
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
inet_interfaces = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
message_size_limit = 0
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
mydestination = ks4000003.ip-198-245-60.net, localhost, localhost.localdomain
myhostname = ks4000003.ip-198-245-60.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks $virtual_mailbox_limit_maps
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relayrecipientmaps.cf
relayhost = 
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
smtp_destination_rate_delay = 1s
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,  permit_mynetworks,  check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf, reject_rhsbl_sender dsn.rfc-ignorant.org,   reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client list.dsbl.org,    reject
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
smtpd_error_sleep_time = 1s
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 20
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_helo_restrictions = check_helo_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf,  permit_sasl_authenticated,     reject_non_fqdn_hostname,     reject_invalid_hostname,   regexp:/etc/postfix/helo.regexp,    permit_mynetworks,     reject
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/rbl_whitelist,     check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf,   check_recipient_access regexp:/etc/postfix/sender_access.regexp,    permit_sasl_authenticated,  permit_mynetworks,  reject_unknown_recipient_domain,    reject_unauth_pipelining,   reject_unauth_destination,  reject_unverified_sender,   reject_unauth_destination,  reject_unlisted_recipient,  reject_invalid_hostname,    reject_non_fqdn_sender,     reject_unknown_sender_domain,   reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,  reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,   reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,     reject_rbl_client dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net,  reject_rbl_client truncate.gbudb.net
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sender_login_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-sender-access.cf
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,  permit_mynetworks,  check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/sender_access.regexp mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf,    reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain,   reject_unknown_hostname,    reject
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 10
smtpd_tls_ask_ccert = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
transport_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_domains = 
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Maybe my configuration is not good, I really need some help... How may I block these Emails? 
Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `permit_mynetworks` is set under `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` . `mynetworks` is set to `127.0.0.0/8` and its IPv6 equivalent.
This allows unauthenticated mail from localhost. There is likely a rogue process that's just sending mail to localhost.
If you remove that option, at least the mails may stop. But you'll still need to find the rogue process.
You may want to go through your processlist for processes that are suspicious.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I am running Linux Malware Detect right now. While modifying post config (the exact same one that I posted in the post below) in order to secure it better, I did get another problem; @hotmail.com addresses (and also many others such as @gmail.com) get the following error when sending an Email to an address hosted on my server : http://pastebin.com/i3N0js53 - Do you have any idea looking at my config? thanks :)

Comment: Can you repost the postconf as it is now?

Comment: I rolled back to a previous configuration, this seem to work now, but I'm not sure if it's okay... if you want to take a look, it would be very kind : http://pastebin.com/raw/F7JZpqu4
Also, for a quick fix, as all spam senders have "msg" in the name, I tried to use a regexp on 'smtpd_sender_restrictions' in order to ban 
    /^msg(.*)@(.*)\.(.*)$/ REJECT   
but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Linux Malware Detect has found 5 PHP suspect files. I look at some of them and there are shell_exec functions in it, which may explain why there is no trace of PHP processes in mail log in spammy emails. I cleaned it up, and opened back my outgoing port, I will see if it was the problem. LMD seems to be a very good tool though, I would recommend it to anyone having such problems...

Comment: LMD seems to have solved my problem.

Comment: Update : LMD couldn't find some malwares ... which ISP Protect did (so far). It's worth trying the trial free scan... I found 20+ malwares LMD couldn't find and which were sending spam all over the universe. If it keeps working well, it's not an expensive price to pay for a clean server and less stress.